# Swift loop through array one by one with pauses in between

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, delay, dispatch

I'm trying to have a function that will loop through an array of Ints, and for each item, depending on its value, pop up a particular message for a second or so, then have the message disappear, and then move on to the next item in the array.  I was able to figure out how to use DISPATCH to create a "delay" for the message disappearing - but I'm still ending up with all the messages popping up at once.

Separately, I have created a function called "offAll()" that turns off all the messages, which I'm trying to call using DISPATCH at the end of the for loop -- but as I said, it's still showing all messages at once.   (I've also tried putting the DISPATCH statement into each of the case statements individually, but that didn't seem to help either.)

FYI, I'm using Swift 4, in XCode.  Thank you!!

```
 func popUp(){
    for item in order{
        if item == 0 {
            firstLabel.text = "ME!"
        } else if item == 1 {
            secondLabel.text = "ME!"
        } else if item == 2 {
            thirdLabel.text = "ME!"
        } else {
            fourthLabel.text = "ME!"
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
          self.offAll()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of the function and step through it until the end. It should hopefully make it clear to you why they're all appearing at once.

Comment: Another helpful thought. If you have 4 popovers saying "ME!", you probably should have the label text say something different *among* each of those four - it helps rule out other issues.

Answer (score 2):

The messages appear all together because the for cycle is not asynchronous and you are not pausing it. A solution could be using a timer to delay each message.
You can call this timer wherever you want to start showing the messages.
I'm assuming order is an array.

```
    var item = 0
    let popUpTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        //removes all popups
        self.offAll()
        if item == 0 {
            firstLabel.text = "ME!"
        } else if item == 1 {
            secondLabel.text = "ME!"
        } else if item == 2 {
            thirdLabel.text = "ME!"
        } else {
            fourthLabel.text = "ME!"
        }
        item = item + 1
        if item >= order.count { //not order.count - 1 so the last popup can be removed
            //stops the timer when all popups are shown
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    })
```

This will show a popup every second and remove the previous one before showing the next one.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This was very helpful!